# Adding an SQL Interval to a timestamp value

Tags: sql, sql-update, sybase

Could you please assist with below:

I have a relation called `branch_process_control` which consist of a field `run_time_not_before` (datetime).

Also I have a function that returns a current date and time `dbo.udf_getdate`.

I want to run an update statement to set `run_time_not_before` = todays date and be 1 minutes ahead from current time.

Is the following correct? I am using DBVisualizer Sybase Database.

```
update branch_process_control 
    set run_time_not_before = dbo.udf_getdate + (interval '1 minute') 
where branch_process_control_guid ='f7bb0acc6a4947908f34dfb0bf0e3adf' 
 and  process_name = 'Branch MonthEnd Action Processor'
```

Comment: hi  @a_horse_with_no_name I am Using postgresql

Comment: If you're using Postgres why is the post tagged as Sybase? Perhaps change the tags.

Comment: I have changed the tag to Sybase @RichCampbell

Comment: Which Sybase database production are you using specifically as 'interval '1 minute' isn't valid syntax for example for Sybase ASE you would usually use the dateadd function?

Comment: @RichCampbell yes, am using Sybase ASE

Comment: update branch_process_control 
    set run_time_not_before = DATEADD( minute, 5, getdate())
where branch_process_control_guid ='f7bb0acc6a4947908f34dfb0bf0e3adf' 
 and  process_name = 'Branch MonthEnd Action Processor'